# PowerShell script to sort an array ascending order and return last value

Tags: powershell

I am having below PowerShell script which does not result in the sorting order I want.

```
$string = @("Project-a1-1", "Project-a1-10", "Project-a1-2", "Project-a1-5", "Project-a1-6", "Project-a1-8")

$myobjecttosort=@()

$string | ForEach{
    $myobjecttosort+=New-Object PSObject -Property @{    
    'String'=$_
    'Numeric'=[int]([regex]::Match($_,'\d+')).Value
    }
}

$myobjecttosort | Sort-Object Numeric | Select Numeric,String | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

The output of the above script:

Numeric String

---

```
  1 Project-a1-5
  1 Project-a1-6
  1 Project-a1-8
  1 Project-a1-1
  1 Project-a1-10
  1 Project-a1-2
```

Required Output

```
  1 Project-a1-1
  2 Project-a1-2
  3 Project-a1-5
  4 Project-a1-6
  5 Project-a1-8
  6 Project-a1-10
```

Also, I want always output to be returned as the last value so here output would be `Project-a1-10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sort-Object` accepts a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks?view=powershell-5.1) allowing for a more robust sort. With that said, just like any other object in the pipeline, the objects are accessible via `$PSItem`, or `$_`. So, a quick way to go about this is splitting the string at the `-` selecting just the ending numerical digits, then casting `[int]` to the result to sort by.

```
$string = "Project-a1-1", "Project-a1-10", "Project-a1-2", "Project-a1-5", "Project-a1-6", "Project-a1-8"
$string | 
    Sort-Object -Property { [int]($_ -replace '^.*?(?=\d+$)') } |
    % { $i = 1 } {
        '{0} {1}' -f $i++, $_
    }
```

The above yields:

```
1 Project-a1-1
2 Project-a1-2
3 Project-a1-5
4 Project-a1-6
5 Project-a1-8
6 Project-a1-10
```

Passing the sorted items to `%` (alias to `Foreach-Object`), we can then format a new string giving it an index # to each string starting at 1.

Comment: I think this each one is a good answer, however, what If I want to remove indices from output like 1,2,3...?

Comment: @DevDeveloper, I dont believe I understand what it is you're after. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I mean to say if input array was like this, Project-a1-v1, Project-a1-v10, Project-a1-v14, how to sort them. this does not work. [string[]]$arrayFromFile = Get-Content -Path 'd:\log.txt'
$finalArray= $arrayFromFile.split('')

$finalArray | 
    Sort-Object -Property {[int] substring(($_ -split '-')[-1],1) }  | Select-Object -Last 1,

Comment: That wasnt in the question, but I've updated my answer. Just using `-Replace` rather than `-Split` to leave just the last numbers to sort by. Is that what you're after?